# Create nodes conditionally when loading nodes from csv in Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

I have a data set in csv format. One of the fields is "elem_type". Based on this type I need to create different types nodes and give to the "columns" of my csv a different name based on the "elem_type" when loading the data using csv load, any way to do that?

My csv has no header and the data look like this:

```
0, 123, Marco, Ciao
1, 345, Merceds, Car, Yellow
2, 987, Boat, 150cm
```

Based on the first colmuns that is my "elem_type" i want to load the data and define 3 types of nodes (Person, Car, Boat) and also based on the elem_type define different header

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to pre-parse the csv file into separate files for each label. It will make the cypher for import so much easier. In the following I use a little trick by wrapping the CASE command inside a FOREACH:

```
load csv from "file:///test.csv" as line
foreach (i in case when line[0] = '0' then [1] else [] end | 
  merge (p:Person {id: line[1]}) set p.name = line[2] )
foreach (i in case when line[0] = '1' then [1] else [] end | 
  merge (c:Car {id: line[1]}) set c.name = line[2], c.color = line[4] )
foreach (i in case when line[0] = '2' then [1] else [] end | 
  merge (b:Boat {id: line[1]}) set b.name = line[2] )
```

Also, don't forget to add indexes on the properties you are merging on.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I tried it and worked fine! Do you know if i can get the same result using "neo4j (admin) import" so i can define the "header csv" because in my real dataset the 3 types of nodes that i have to define has got a lot of attribute and write them all in the code it's a bit difficult

Comment: Be advised that the neo4j-admin import creates a new database. You can't use it to work with an existing database. Because of this restriction, I have hardly worked with it and can't give you help here.
Also, you would normally parse the csv data, otherwise any property in Neo4j will just be a string. Converting the csv fields to numbers, DataTimes, boolean,.. will help you later when working with the database. Because of this, you will have to enumerate each attribute anyway